# jQtouch + Phonegap: Document head setup

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, jqtouch, cordova

I've recently built a webapp using jQTouch & packaged in PhoneGap (both latest versions).  I'm now attempting to optimise the app, and was hoping to get some information on how to correctly setup the  of the document.

Currently I simply have the jQTouch javascript (no phonegap.js), and it seems to package and run ok on the iphone.  Is there a best practice when setting up the  for this combination (ie. should i include the jqt.js & jqt initialisation; phonegap.js & initialisation; or both)

Issues I'm experiencing with the app (which may or may not be related to the above):

1. App has a long load time - loading screen is about 10second wait (accelerometer & gps turned off in phonegap)
2. App is incredibly slow (unusable) on iPhone 3G + iOS4.
   NB: Works just fine in iPhone 4 + ios4, iPhone 3G + iOS 3, and iPhone 3GS iOS4.

Thanks!
Glen

Answer (score 1):

A good option that you could use now would be [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/), it's a jQuery-compatible library that was built to be light-weight in order to fix these types of performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda behind where you are at the moment - I've written one simple phonegap based app using jquery/jspec/phonegap, and it appears to work pretty well...but I've only tested it on the iphone 4 simulator (haven't registered with the apple developer program yet). Curious to see where you get with this.

I had heard (from a direct competitor, so take it with a grain of salt) that jQuery might be 'slow' on the iphone - maybe xUI is the right way to go? http://xuijs.com/

I'm sticking with jQuery til I know different.

---

I'm assuming you're using the 'min.js' in your final releases?

Comment: Ya, definitely using min versions wherever possible.  I've written a bit of js (custom) for it too. So there's quite a bit.  I did know about XUI, but noticed that it didn't seem to be an active project - no real activity on github compared to jqtouch/jquery - which is quite active by comparison.  I'll take a closer look too tho, so thanks!! I'll do anything to speed this thing up.